# Reducing the height of navbar (without compromising the beauty) so that it gets chucked with the slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was writing a page in bootstrap when I stuck an issue. I have made a `menu-bar` or a `navbar` in bootstrap. Just below the navbar there is a slider. But there is an extra space in between the navbar and the slider. When I debugged, I found that extra space was of the navbar.
How could I remove the white-space between navbar and slider so that they are attached to each other.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3488/) of it.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the bootstrap navbar includes a 20 pixel margin. If you remove the margin by overriding the default bootstrap css they will be connected.

Add this to your css:

```
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3490/

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your fiddle you have

```
.navbar {margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

so you could also override  it inline directly inserting style in html-markup...

(you can set it to 0 or none)